# Can not modify stored procedure on Azure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm new to Azure SQL database.
I managed to migrate my database to the cloud.

Now I'm trying to modify a stored procedure using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (the latest edition - 2014). But get the following error message:

> USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new
>   connection to connect to a different database.

Any idea how can I do this? 
Also, is there any alternatives to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to work with Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE in sql is used to switch between databases not to modify stored procedures. You cannot use USE on Azure SQL as per the specification. You should be able to right-click on the database name in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and select New Query, or you can use the dropdown list in the menu to switch databases. You can then use ALTER PROCEDURE (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189762.aspx) to alter your procedure.

You can use Visual Studio as an alternative to SSMS but IMHO Visual Studio is not as productive. It doesnt matter which client you use though, because USE wont work in any of them.

Comment: Thank you very much. The USE statement stayed there since I migrated my local database to Azure's cloud. I would expect them to remove it. Anyways, if I remove the USE statement and trying to modify the stored procedure then it says that 'Invalid object name 'dbo.MyStoredProcedureName' and does not alter the SP. Any ideas about that?

Comment: What is the result if you execute this statement in the query window you are using 
SELECT db_name()

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tries simple query 'select * from dbo.tblusers' got the same message 'Invalid object name 'dbo.tblusers'.

Comment: Sorry, I just understood your request. I tried it and got 'master'. I guess that is the problem right there. How can I make SSMS to work on my private database?

Comment: There is a dropdown list in SSMS usually below the FIle Menu that will have master written in it. That shows you the context of the query window you are in. Select the database you want from that list and it will change the context of the query window to that database. Alternatively, select the database in the object explorer, right click, and new query will open a new query window in the context of that database

Comment: I don't have SSMS. I am always interacting with azure so what should I do for alter SP?